# Rejecting Old Browsers in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I can think of several different ways to redirect a request to my MVC 4 application if the client is a browser that I do not want to support.  Can anyone suggest what they feel would be the best way to do this?  Http Handler?, Global.asax Session Start?, Custom Base Controller?  Something else?

Essentially, I want to redirect all requests to a page that states that IE 7 and below is not supported with information and hyperlinks on how to upgrade their browser.

---

Solution

```
    <rule name="UserAgent MSIE Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="MSIE 7.0b|MSIE 7.0|MSIE 6.0b|MSIE 6.0|MSIE 5.5b1|MSIE 5.5|MSIE 5.0|MSIE 5.01|MSIE 4.0" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://ffds1.com/NotSupported.html" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea would be to use the IIS [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) to check the user agent and redirect as required. But this requires IIS 7 and knowledge of how to configure the IIS URL Rewrite. I personally haven't done this but plan to use this method for almost the same problem. What I like about this method is that it can be changed on the fly if need be without making a change to the web application or any of it's underlying code.

Comment: I found this to be a great solution.  I was already implementing the IIS Rewrite Module so I adapted a rule snippet to detect mobile devices to detecting MSIE version in User Agent Header and redirecting to a plain html page.  See above for snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said you could do this any number of ways, but I would create an [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) as it will be the cleanest way and will work across any ASP.Net application.

A module runs on every request... which is kind of what you are looking for.